# How to find equivalence class of this relation?

Tags: relations

In solving this problem:

> Let $R$ be an equivalence relation on the set $A = \{a,b,c,d\}$, defined by partitions $P = \{\{a,d\},\{b,c\}\}$. Determine the elements of the equivalence relation and also find the equivalence classes of $R$.

I found the elements as asked by the first part of the question.
$$
R = \{ \{a,a\}, \{a,d\}, \{d,a\}, \{d,d\}, \{b,b\}, \{c,c\}, \{c,b\}, \{b,c\} \}
$$

Not sure about equivalence class.

Comment: Do you know the definition of equivalence classes? They are really really **really** tightly connected to the partitions...

Comment: hint: start to write down the full equivalence class of $a$.

Comment: I have no idea what equivalence class is!

Comment: maybe try google?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFexPRbJLlw

After seeing this video, the answer is:

[a] = [d] = {a,d}

[b] = [c] = {b,c}

Answer (score 1):

Give that partition, you ought to define $\sim$ on $A$ as
$$x\sim y\quad\mbox{iff  ``$x$ and $y$ are in the same subset"}.$$
So it is easy to see that there are only two equivalences classes: those mentioned by Code Man.